# Need to find specific records from two tables with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables

magento_customerbalance -mcb

```
column -
1. balance_id
2. customer_id
3. website_id
4. amount
5. base_currency_code
```

customer_entity_varchar -cev

```
column - 
1. value
2. attribute_id
3. entity_id
4. value
```

I've tried to find customer_id from mcb which does not have cev.attribute_id 5 with the following SQL queries

Query #1:

```
SELECT COUNT(mcb.customer_id) 
FROM magento_customerbalance mcb;
```

Results :

```
total customer from mcb =121
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT mc.customer_id 
FROM magento_customerbalance mc 
INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar cev ON cev.entity_id = mc.customer_id
WHERE cev.attribute_id = 5;
```

Results :

```
    total customers from mcv with attribute id 5 = 100
```

3. 121 -100 =21

customer who does not have attribute id 5 = 21

How we can get these 21 mcb.customer_id records with a SQL query?

In cev table there are multiple attribute ids for same customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the not exists operator with a correlated subquery as the following:

```
SELECT mcb.customer_id /* add other columns as needed */
FROM magento_customerbalance mcb
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM customer_entity_varchar cev
  WHERE cev.entity_id = mcb.customer_id AND
        cev.attribute_id = 5
)
```

And if you want only customer_ids which have an entity_id in the cev table add this condition:

```
AND EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM customer_entity_varchar cev
  WHERE cev.entity_id = mcb.customer_id 
)
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/l1B6Wi8_)

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried not equal to 5, !=5 ?

```
SELECT  mc.customer_id FROM magento_customerbalance mc inner join customer_entity_varchar 
    cev on cev.entity_id = mc.customer_id
    where cev.attribute_id != 5 OR cev.attributee IS NULL;
```

Comment: I've tried != also but getting more than 21 records 
so I am not sure they are same

Comment: Can i know the relationship between two tables ? is one to many, many to many or one to one? 
If one to many or many to many then the result will more than 21 records as you have duplicate records after joining the table.

Comment: I've edited the question.
Can you please check the last line?